# Rust memory sharing between thread

Tags: memory, websocket, rust, mutex, shared-memory

I'm trying to share a [Handler](https://docs.rs/ws/0.9.0/ws/trait.Handler.html)(for websocket communication) and its properties between different threads using Mutex and Arc.

```rust
let shared_server = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Server { out: None }));
let c_shared_server = shared_server.clone();
thread::spawn(move || {
    listen(format!("{}:{}", String::from("127.0.0.1"), 3012), |out| {
        c_shared_server.lock().unwrap().out = Some(out.clone());
        move |msg| {
            Ok(())
        }
    }).unwrap()
});
let ten_millis = time::Duration::from_millis(1000);
thread::sleep(ten_millis);
println!("{:?}", shared_server.lock().unwrap());
```

> Server { out: None }

out shouldn't be None here, I want to use it then, any idea how i could accomplish this ?

Comment: And why should it not be? Have you timed how long it takes for `listen` to call the callback you provided? Is it even being called? If so, is it called after or before 1s? This `listen()` method is opaque and not provided in the question; it could be taking 6 hours to do anything, for all we know.

Comment: Why don't you use a channel?

Comment: Thanks @SébastienRenauld found out out is called when a client connect actually ...

Comment: @LouisBeaumont Always investigate with either a breakpoint or a good old `println!()` before assuming it's a problem within a core part of the language :-)

Comment: I wasn't assuming it's a problem of the language, was asking how to have out different of None :), @FrenchBoiethios I don't know about channels but will look into it thanks (but there is so few examples unfortunately)

Comment: @LouisBeaumont That's the way you do what you want in Rust, not with a global variable. The ergonomic and performance are better.

Comment: @LouisBeaumont Most people rarely use the core networking toolkit, preferring to layer `tokio` on top due to its significant advantages, particularly when handling more than one connection.